# How to create a bidirectional bind volume in Docker?

Tags: docker, apache, binding, dockerfile, docker-volume

I would like to have a bidirectional volume in container. I will show a basic example:

`$ docker container run -d -p 80:80 -v $HOME/htdocs:/var/www/html httpd`

Imagine if I extend that image and copy a content like `index.html` in the `/var/www/html` folder at the build process, but when I bind a empty folder `$HOME/htdocs`, the content of `/var/www/html` gets overwrited.

Is there a way to avoid that default behaviour of overwriting of the destination of bind volume? I expect to be bidirectional, the content of `/var/www/html` should be copied to `$HOME/htdocs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is that if you mount a host volume the container volume gets overwritten.

If you mount a new docker-volume the contents of the container version gets copied to the docker-volume.

If you want to have a different behavior you have to build that mechanism yourself, which is very possible, but custom

Comment: Currently I have that custom solution outside docker logic, but for example: I was expecting to have a thing like Virtualbox VM Shared Folders logic, they are bidirectional.

Comment: Oh, the mount if not mounted `:ro` is bi-directional, but not from the start.

Comment: ```:ro``` stands for readonly mount, that way the container application would not be able to modify the content of bind volume and It will give a serious file permission issues in that folder. The main issue is the initial overwriting in the bind process. The rest it works fine.

Comment: As I described above. The mounting behavior is as described and fixed.